# c++ overloaded function and templates

Tags: c++

I am learning how to use templates in conjunction with function overloading, but I can't seem to grasp it; specifically, I have 2 functions with the same name, one accepts 2 int parameters, the other 3 int parameters. I need them to return, respectively, a double/triple pointer to a type which should be defined by the function caller; in other words:

```
template <typename T>
T** Foo(int p0, int p1){
    T** ret = nullptr;
    // ... do stuff with ret ...
    return ret;
}

template <typename T>
T*** Foo(int p0, int p1, int p2){
    T*** ret = nullptr;
    // ... do stuff with ret ...
    return ret;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double**  d2 = Foo(1, 2);
    double*** d3 = Foo(1, 2, 3);
    int**     i2 = Foo(1, 2);
    int**     i3 = Foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

I was expecting d2 and i2 to be returned by the first Foo(), d3 and i3 by the second; instead I get Errors C2780 and C2783 from each one of the calls in main(). What am I missing?

Comment: What do you expect `T` to be in those calls?

Comment: I expect T to be double for the first two calls, int for the others 2

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to know that? All that the compiler can use, to figure out the template parameters, are the parameters to the template function.

Comment: Template deduction works only for the function arguments. It could not be done for the function return type.

Comment: @code_fodder Read again, it's not really about the question: _This question has been asked before and **already has an answer**._ The OP isn't supposed to know that beforehand, that's why users are here who know about it and can close the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I disagree... the OP has posted code that is not working and is asking for help. It is a minimal, compliable, example. This exact code has not been posted before... has it?

Comment: @code_fodder Again, it's not about the exact same question or code. The point is the question is already answered how this works in the duplicate post.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok fair point... but still, the question that was referenced was different since it was overload by return value. However, I still don't see the point of closing questions... let people answer, its not like we are de-cluttering by closing them since they now exist and appear in searches.... anyway, that's probably one for meta-stack-exchange I guess

Comment: @code_fodder Closing as a duplicate isn't a punishment. It's an efficient way to point someone to an existing answer, and to prevent other people from wasting their time duplicating that answer. It also ensures that answers are collected in one place for easy reference, rather than being spread around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot automatically deduce the template parameter (because it is only dependant on the return type and not any of the arguments). You should use this code instead:

```
double**  d2 = Foo<double>(1, 2);
double*** d3 = Foo<double>(1, 2, 3);
int**     i2 = Foo<int>(1, 2);
int***    i3 = Foo<int>(1, 2, 3);
```

(Note I also made a correction on the final line: you had `int**` instead of `int***`)